# Obtener fecha en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, datetime

Necesito obtener la fecha del sistema con fecha, hora, mminutos, segundos y milisegundos en node.js y luego convertirlo en un integer.

Alguna idea?

Gracias!!

Comment: Para hacer búsquedas es mejor que uses Google o Bing. Si tienes algún problema real y específico al obtener la fecha o convertir este dato en entero, agrega un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender tu planteamiento.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  es una solicitud de búsqueda no un problema real.

Comment: pues dale......

Comment: @java005 Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Es esto lo que quieres?

```js
let now= new Date();
console.log('La fecha actual es',now);
console.log('UNIX time:',now.getTime());
```

No es sólo de Node, la clase Date es estándar en [toda implementación de ECMAScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)

Por aclarar, copio de la web de MDN:

> El valor devuelto por el metodo `getTime()` es el número de
>   milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Hola... mira, necesito algo asi:
var fecha = 10/09/2018
var hora = 12:00:22:133
var total = 10092018120022133

Comment: ¿Para qué lo quieres así? Ese formato te va a dar muchos problemas, ya que no puedes comparar fechas de manera sencilla y los días menores a 10 serán más problemáticos

Comment: Necesito que sea el ID en una base de datos, crees que sea posible?

Comment: la fecha no deberia ser el id en una base de datos.. nunca... porque?? ademas puede que exista la posibilidad de que justo dos registros ingresen al mismo tiempo...

Comment: En ese caso yo usaría el UNIX Time, pero realmente no me parece una buena idea (puedes tener dos entradas creadas en el mismo milisegundo, cada instrucción necesita apenas nanosegundos en una máquina actual para ser ejecutada)

Comment: Son las especificaciones que me dieron, solo debo de seguirlas :(

Comment: @java005 mas alla de que sean las especificaciones (y esta ok), deja en claro que esto puede llevar a errores de clave.

Comment: @gbianchi lo hare! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var dat= new Date(); //Obtienes la fecha
var dat2 = Date.parse(dat); //Lo parseas para transformarlo

console.log(dat);
console.log(dat2)
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Es equivalente a lo que he respondido, creo

Comment: Mmm... No había mirado tu respuesta y tienes razón ya que responden lo mismo, solo cambia algo la sintaxis en la llamada al métodos "getTime()" y yo le di un "parse", igual dejaré la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve, a no ser que haya un problema con ello y yo no lo sepa xD. Saludos.

Comment: No, no hay problema :)